# Revit, Python: How to get the current build of an open project file?

Tags: python, revit

I have a python file that needs to read the Version Year that the open project is currently in (for instance, the current project is in Revit 2020).  Once I get that, I can pass that info on to other portions of the script - basically telling it what folder to find the families for that version.

Make sense???

Problem is, I can't seem to find a clue for what I need to look for to get the version.

Answer (score 0):

All right, paint me stupid. Here's the PRETTY DAMN EASY ANSWER!

```
app = doc.Application

data = app.VersionNumber
print data
```

I like simple!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at the utility shared in this [recent comment](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/basic-file-info-and-rvt-file-version.html#comment-4927991760) on The Building Coder discussion of [Basic File Info and RVT File Version](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/basic-file-info-and-rvt-file-version.html).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the additional info.  You must have been up on another mountain top or just running behind - your response time is slipping!!!  Take care and thanks again.